# Does affine equivariance implies shape unbiasedness?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Basically, I'm dealing with an algorithm that, given an $n\times p$ data matrix $\pmb X$ with iid rows, returns $\hat{\pmb\sigma}(\pmb X)\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$. To simplify things, I will also assume that $\pmb \varSigma$ (the true covariance matrix of $\pmb X$) has full rank. The algorithm is demonstrably affine equivariant, e.g.:

$$\hat{\pmb \sigma}(\pmb A\pmb X+\pmb 1_n\pmb b')=\pmb A\hat{\pmb \sigma}(\pmb X)\pmb A'$$

--$\forall$ non singular $\pmb A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ and $p$-vector $\pmb b$.

However, it is not known whether the algorithm satisfies a particular form of unbiasedness. More precisely, the interest is in establishing whether (or possibly under which conditions) the estimate returned by the algorithm is *shape* unbiased. By this I mean that:

$$E[\hat{\pmb\sigma}(\pmb X)/|\hat{\pmb\sigma}(\pmb X)|^{1/p}]=\pmb \varSigma/|\pmb \varSigma|^{1/p}$$

where for any $p$ by $p$ symmetric matrix $\pmb B$,  $|\pmb B|$ denotes the determinant of $\pmb B$.

The problem is that, in this case, establishing shape unbiasedness appears quiet complicated. The question, I guess, is whether (or possibly under what set of additional conditions does) affine equivariance implies shape unbiasedness.

Comment: Can you clear up the statement of affine equivariance? Currently none of the operations are well defined (matrix multiplication where dimensions don't match and addition of matrix and vector). What, if any, distributional assumptions on $\mathbf X $ are you making? (Independent rows?)

Comment: Some things to consider: when $\sigma(X)=0$ (the $p\times p$ zero matrix) the procedure is trivially equivariant but obviously not unbiased. More generally, when $\sigma$ is equivariant unbiased and $p\gt 1$, the procedure $\tau(X)=\lambda\sigma(X)$ is also equivariant but when $\lambda^p\ne \lambda$ it must be biased. This suggests that dividing $\sigma(X)$ by its determinant might not be the right definition of "unbiased" to be using.

Comment: Hi @user: The edit is helpful. It  doesn't appear to address my remarks on the equivariance definition, though. Cheers.

Comment: @cardinal: I think I have fixed these oversights. whuber: thanks for the comments. I have appended the definition of equivariance to exclude trivial equivariance you allude to. Concerning your comment on the type of unbiasedness: the type used here (shape unbiasedness) is the important one because when the data is elliptical and *if* estimator is shape unbiased, finding the 'correct' scaling factor is a much simpler problem.

Comment: Did you mean "unbiasedness" in the title? It reads "unibiasedness"

Comment: (Due to lack of answers on CV, this question has been migrated to Math at the OP's request.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In [Robust Statistics: Theory and Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470010924), the authors prove in 6.12.2 (page 217) that affine equivariant estimators are consistent for elliptical distributions in the sense that if $\pmb x \sim \mathcal{f}(\pmb x, \pmb \mu , \pmb \Sigma)$, then 
\begin{equation}
\hat{\pmb \mu}_\infty=\pmb \mu, \; \hat{\pmb \Sigma}_\infty=c\Sigma
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a constant. The consistency of the form $\hat{\pmb \Sigma}_\infty=c\Sigma$ incidentally also implies shape unbiasedness.